# CSS Skew Jagged Edges on iPad

Tags: css, ipad, webkit, skew

I have a site that uses CSS skews extensively as part of the design. Using backface-visibility solved the jagged edge problem, except for on iPad. In every other webkit browser, iphone included, the edges are smooth, but for some reason iPad is not behaving. Here is the code for the skew:

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
backface-visibility:         hidden;
overflow:                    hidden;

-webkit-transform: skewX(16deg);
-moz-transform:    skewX(16deg);
-ms-transform:     skewX(16deg);
transform:         skewX(16deg);

/* IE8+ */ 
-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=0.28674538575880865, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand')";

/* IE6 and 7 */ 
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=1, M12=0.28674538575880865, M21=0, M22=1, SizingMethod='auto expand');
```

This is the site: [acumen.org](http://acumen.org)

Answer (score 7):

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
backface-visibility:         hidden;
```

along with this just add following line:

```
outline: 1px solid transparent;
```